# How can I call an Asp.Net MVC Put method via httpie?

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given a new Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Api application, which has the method

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        lastval = "b " + value;
    }
}
```

How do we call this method via **httpie**? I tried

```
http PUT localhost:20780/api/values/3 value="test"
```

which calls the web api method passing the correct id 3, but the value "test" does not arrive, it is null in the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the controller expect form-encoded data? If yes, then you need to use the [`--form, -f`](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#forms) option. It's because HTTPie sends JSON by default:

```
http --form PUT localhost:20780/api/values/3 value="test"
```